# Guids not mapping with Column Attribute EF 6

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures, mapping, guid

The results from a stored proc are not mapping properly FOR GUIDs only (uniqueidentifiers in SQL)

```
menu.Sites = db.Database
.SqlQuery<Site>("get_application_sitemap @application_user_id, @application_name", 
new SqlParameter("application_user_id",id), 
new SqlParameter("application_name",applicationName)).ToList();
```

The Site class is shown below

```
 public class Site : EntityBase
{
    public Guid ApplicationWebpageGuid
    {
        get { return application_webpage_guid; }
    }

    public Guid application_webpage_guid { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentApplicationWebpageGuid
    {
        get { return parent_application_webpage_guid ?? Guid.Empty; }
    }
    public Guid? parent_application_webpage_guid { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public int Children { get; set; }
}
```

The major issue is that the column names coming out of the stored proc are lower cased and underscore spaced. The way I am "mapping" and I use that term loosely is not something I like. The three properties Name, Url, and Children are mapping fine. The casing seems to have no effect, but the underscore spacing is causing me issues. Is there a way to map to a stored procedure? I can't make any changes to the stored proc without causing a major headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getting Entity Framework raw query to respect attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573206/getting-entity-framework-raw-query-to-respect-attributes)

So you are running into the issue where EF is actually ignoring the attributes that you are putting on the column. It doesn't look like they fixed it in EF 7 so good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In entity framework you can map column names using `FluentAPI` like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Site>() 
            .Property(t => t.ParentApplicationWebpageGuid) 
            .HasColumnName("parent_application_webpage_guid");
```

Or with data annotations like this:

```
[Column(“parent_application_webpage_guid")] 
public String ParentApplicationWebpageGuid {get;set;}
```

References:

[Mapping a CLR Property to a Specific Column in the Database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591617.aspx#1.7)

[Mapping Tables And Columns using Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj591583.aspx#TableColumn)

Comment: I have tried the data annotations, but I will give the mapping a shot.

Comment: Scratch that, just realised what's going on. From documentation for Database.SqlQuery - it "creates a raw SQL query that will return elements of the given generic type. The type can be any type that has properties that **match the names of the columns** returned from the query."

Comment: That is probably why the other three are working. But I want to map the columns to properties on the Site object without the underscores. I am trying to use the map column technique right now and it is yelling about "ApplicationWebpageGuid doesn't have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name." Right now I am trying to get to the bottom of this one.